# Reproducing a question style in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1cm]
     \item A question    

     \medskip     
     \hrulefill 

     \medskip     
     \hrulefill 
  [1]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Using the above code as a starting point, I'd like to reproduce the following question style, so that there's a gap between the mark for a question and the main body of the question (and the horizontal lines for working out) as shown. Any help appreciated.[image]

Comment: What is that [1]?  Does it have a relation with 1 in question? is it points or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `minipage` environment, as follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[%
    label=\textbf{\arabic*},leftmargin=*, labelsep=1cm
    ]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
\item A question    

     \medskip     
     \hrulefill 

     \medskip     
     \hrulefill
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.1\linewidth}
[1]
\end{minipage}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Macro for your **"questions"** which makes it way easier to understand. I have also defined a `tab` preference for your desired margin. You can modify the macros to what you prefer.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}
\def\question#1#2{%
    {#1}\\
    \medskip     
    \rule{0.75\textwidth}{.5pt} 

     \medskip     
    \rule{0.75\textwidth}{.5pt}\tab{}
  [{#2}]}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1cm]
     \item \question{Calculate the integral...}{4}
     \item \question{Approximate the geometric space of...}{7}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An answer with a counter seems better option to me instead of enumerate environment.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\newlength{\NumberWidth}
\newlength{\AfterWidth}
\setlength{\NumberWidth}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\AfterWidth}{1cm}
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{lines}
\newcommand{\Question}[2][6]{\stepcounter{question}\setcounter{lines}{0}\noindent\parbox[t]{\NumberWidth}{\thequestion}\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\dimexpr(\NumberWidth+\AfterWidth)\relax\relax}{{\bfseries #2}\par\loop \ifnum\value{lines}<#1\stepcounter{lines}\hrulefill\par\ifnum\value{lines}<\numexpr#1\relax\vspace{0.5cm}\fi\repeat}\par\hfill[1]}


\begin{document}
\Question[4]{This is a question}

\Question[6]{This is another question}
\end{document}
```

[image]

PS: Just to "drop" the idea.